# Window navigator standalone and event listener - Javascript

Tags: javascript, event-listener, iphone-standalone-web-app

I am new in Javascript. I am trying to study and understand the following part of code:

```
if(("standalone" in window.navigator) && window.navigator.standalone){ //1

   var node = false;

   document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

   node = event.target;

   while(node.nodeName !== "A" && node.nodeName !== "HTML") {
   node = node.parentNode;
   }

   if('href' in node && node.href.indexOf('http') !== -1 && 
   (node.href.indexOf(document.location.host) !== -1)){

      event.preventDefault();                                
      document.location.href = node.href;        }                  
    },false);
  }
```

Now, imagine following: you are on a page http://test.gr/index.html and the first condition is true (//1.). There is this link on the page:

```
<a href="http://test.gr/info.html" target="_blank">Info</a>
```

1) Under which circumstances the first condition (//1) is true?

2)What happens after clicking on the link? When the code pass the while loop? Does the link open in the same tab or in a new tab?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Under which circumstances the first condition (//1) is true?

When using Safari browser on iOS, and [setting the apple-mobile-web-app-capable](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193-SW3) meta tag

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

> 2)What happens after clicking on the link? When the code pass the
>   while loop? Does the link open in the same tab or in a new tab?

The while loop transverses up the dom tree from the clicked element till it reaches an Anchor tag or reaches the root HTML element.

The second if statement checks to see if the node that was stopped on is an element with a valid href property, if it is not nothing else happens.

Otherwise `event.preventDefault()` prevents the default action, which in the case of the example Anchor would be to open a new tab. `document.location.href` then changes the current tab to the new location.